# LINQ issue while updating sql server from 2005 to 2008

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql

We are planning to update our production server to 2008 now, but before that we tried to test it on our development server and I am facing some problem in order to connect our websites to it. I was under an impression that by just changing the connection string, it will point to the other server. It is a dot net web application, so do I need to delete and reinsert all the tables in the dbml file. Also, do I need to insert the stored procedures as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reinsert all your tables.  If you have the dbml Connection property set to use the connection string from your application settings file you just have to modify that.  Otherwise you can open up the designer file and change it there but it will get reset anytime you make changes from the UI.

Comment: I just keep getting this error message "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'usf_rolesForLuser', database.." when I just change the connection string property.

Comment: That should tell you the problem. Your ASP user account doesn't have rights to the new SQL Server.

Comment: But I can login using the same username and password on management studio and over there I see that this particular user I am using in my connection String does have the rights to access and execute.

Comment: Check the connection string being used by your datacontext to verify you changed it in the correct place.  DataContext.Connection.ConnectionString

Comment: Yeah, it was about the securables for some stored procedures. After adding execute permissions for them, they were good. Just wondering, why didn't the permissions get copied from the backup copy of the database which was used to load it on the 2008 server.